# when /etc/modules is used?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ubuntu-9.10, modprobe

"# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time." 
my question is when and where the module loading job done?

my first guess is some init scripts in /etc/init.d/ but grep got none. then i think it might be the init ramdisk, but after decompress it, i found conf/modules which is different with /etc/modules.

any idea? thanx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at:

```
/etc/init/module-init-tools.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

In debian that file is read by the initialization files, so in /etc/rcS directory and by the script file S20module-init-tools.
So it's pretty at the beginning and always after udev try to load all the needed modules.

Comment: but find /etc/rcS.d/ | xargs -i grep -l modules {}
returns nothing...

Comment: debtest:/etc/rcS.d# grep modules *
S12mtab.sh:                     /lib/modules/*/volatile)
S20module-init-tools:# Short-Description: Process /etc/modules.
S20module-init-tools:# Description:       Load the modules listed 
in /etc/modules.

S20module-init-tools:# Silently exit if the kernel does not support modules or needs modutils.

S20module-init-tools:[ -f /proc/modules ] || exit 0